# Silverlight Databinding Problem

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a UserControl added to another at design time, in my XAML I set the DataContext for the added control, however I want to use the parents DataContext to control the Visibilty of the UserControl.

How do I achieve this??

```
<UI_Employee:ActionsListView Visibility="{Binding HasActionsThisMonth, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" DataContext="{Binding Path=ActionsThisMonth}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HeaderTitle="This Months Actions" />
```

Doing it the way I have seems to use the newly set DataContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you change the DataContext, that's what all properties will use. So, put the control in a container and have that container's visibility bound to the parent DataContext:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding HasActionsThisMonth, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
   <UI_Employee:ActionsListView DataContext="{Binding Path=ActionsThisMonth}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HeaderTitle="This Months Actions" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Thought that there was maybe a trick I was missing.